# Does EF Core 3.1 support DB First approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, porting

We are porting an `ASP.NET MVC 4.x` application to `ASP.NET Core 3.1`. The current application is using `EF 6.x` DB first approach. As a part of this migration we are going to use `EF Core 3.1` as an alternative to the current `EF 6.x`. So the question is:

**Does EF Core 3.1 support DB First approach?**

If not, what are the options? Are we left with only code first approach?

Appreciate your helps.

Comment: "First" (db, code, model) terminology is misleading. If you are asking for edmx, it isn't (and won't be) supported.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. It supports DB First Approach since .NET Core 1.0 until now. You need to download 4 from nugets

1. EntityFrameworkCore
2. EntityFrameworkCore.Design
3. EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
4. EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Open Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. And enter this below in console.

Default:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourserveraddress;Database=yourdatabase;user id=youruser;password=yourpassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context "YourOwnContext"
```

Saw your comment about "Scaffold-DbContext only creates a Code First model". No, Scaffold-DbContext is Database-First approach.

> "Creating entity & context classes for an existing database is called Database-First approach."

**EDITED**

If you have new update in database and want to update dbcontext, just add -f at end. It will update and overwrite all your dbcontext and model classes.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourserveraddress;Database=yourdatabase;user id=youruser;password=yourpassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context "YourOwnContext" -f
```

If you want to add some data annotations such as [Column], etc in model class, can add -DataAnnotations

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourserveraddress;Database=yourdatabase;user id=youruser;password=yourpassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context "YourOwnContext" -DataAnnotations -f
```

Comment: And is there any EDMX file manipulation in the Scaffold-DbContext?

Comment: No. It creates entity and Dbcontext classes only based on your existing database. EF Core no longer use EDMX.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Can you just run this again to update the models to reflect changes to the database? or do you need to delete the context/POCOs?

Comment: Yes, you need to add - f at the end. It will update your models and context with new changes you made in your database. Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourserveraddress;Database=yourdatabase;user id=youruser;password=yourpassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context "YourOwnContext" - f

Comment: Don't be as negligent as I was and once you open Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console, make sure you have selected the correct "Default project" from the dropdown in the upper toolbox of the console.

Comment: updated post. added 2 commands if anyone need them.

Comment: @Asherguru can we create dbcontext without using scaffold commond in EF Core?

mahendraveeregowda@gmail.com

Comment: Yes, you just need to create new dbcontext class and type/code standard dbcontext yourself. It takes more time and works to do.

Comment: Many thanks asked if we have more than connection string if I can use some of them code first and others as dbfirst and thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, EF Core supports database first via the `Scaffold-DbContext` command, and you can also use EF Core Power Tools. Edmx based modelling is not available with EF Core, only code based modelling.

Comment: Seems that `Scaffold-DbContext` only creates a Code First model based on an existing database and so is not a real DB first approach. I do not know if it manipulates any EDMX file. Am I missing something? For more info see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: The EDMX-based database first is only available in EF 6.  If you really need it, you can use EF 6.3 on .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, would you mind to provide your comment as an answer?

Comment: Please accept EricEJ's answer.  He can edit-in the bit about EDMX if he wants.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I tried EF 6.3 on .Net Core 3.1 but did not find the way to add EDMX. Seems that using EDMX is not possible on any ASP.NET Core project regardless of if is targeting .Net Core or .Net Framework

Comment: See this issue for status and workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1748

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no DB first approach anymore.

What you can do is code first from existing database. With the scaffold command that was already mentioned.

What we do:

- Use scaffold
- Create "scaffold scripts" that control the scaffold process. (For example split the tables into more than one context)
- Create "after scaffold scripts" that repair all mistakes scaffold makes every time. (for example broken data types)
- Create more "after scaffold scripts" that enhance your models with all scaffold does not support. (for example column comments)
- Use partial classes as much as possible to avoid losing changes every time

But in summary there is no satisfactory solution for that.
Be aware that if you want a perfect db first approach you almost rewrite the whole scaffold functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Code First/DB First titles are a bit misleading, but if you're looking for an EDMX based solution, then there's no support in EF Core since EF Core was a completely redesigned ORM.

Instead you can use database scaffolding to create context classes based on your existing database.

Whenever the database changes, you'd simply run the same again so that the existing context classes and their definitions get overwritten by the updated database.

Sounds like a long process, but if you're working on a layered architecture with separated contracts layers, its a lot easier than you think.

https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/database-first-generating-models-from-an-existing-database-using-ef-core

Comment: You're just repeating other answers.

Comment: Actually that's the max we can do with EF Core, afa db first is concerned. But based on how we design our approach we can handle the entities and their changes better.

Comment: Whatever, it's no use to repeat answers. It only adds noise.